# Is it possible to use IntelliJ + PHP + Xdebug + WSL (Ubuntu on Windows)?

Tags: php, windows, debugging, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got a PHP app that I am developing on Windows using IntelliJ rather than PHPStorm (as that is what I have a subscription for).

I want to replicate the production environment and do some live debugging on WSL.

So far, I've tried Mounting \WSL$\Ubuntu.... inside IntelliJ *can read files, can't write) and then I tried setting a local (C:) folder... Inside WSL, I set the root web folder to be this. It works on .txt files, but, I can't get PHP to return anything before the thread terminates.

I'm just a bit stumped here - can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use WSL on production? Otherwise maybe plain VM (Docker, Vagrant) will be better solution.

Comment: No - and I will do a VM if I have to... It's just that, remote debugging adds another layer of complexity (all be it not much) where as technically WSL is local and I was hoping that this would be a lot simpler.

Comment: You could run the IDE in wsl, and use x11 forwarding to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run PhpStorm inside WSL. See  https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-server#not-modifying-your-application-code for more information, but UI will work only in Chrome and Firefox (not in Edge). Found in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242627.

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.